# change dataframe pivot_table headers to save it in an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, flat

I have a nested hearders in a dataframe after pivoting it and I'd like to make it flat, with repeated item on each rows (like in a excel)
May you help me ?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "year": [2022, 2022 , 2021 , 2021 , 2020 ],
  "client": ["A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
  "product" : [ "P1", "P2" , "P1", "P2", "P1"],
  "sales" : [ 10,20, 20, 22, 25]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.pivot_table ( index = ["year","client"] , columns = ["product"] , values = ["sales"] , aggfunc ="sum")
df2

              sales
product      P1     P2
year    client      
2020    C   25.0    NaN
2021    B   20.0    NaN
        C   NaN     22.0
2022    A   10.0    NaN
        B   NaN     20.0
```

where I'd like to get a flat header and reapeated rows :

```
year    client P1   P2  
2020    C   25.0    NaN
2021    B   20.0    NaN
2021    C   NaN     22.0
2022    A   10.0    NaN
2022    B   NaN     20.0
```

many thanks

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `droplevel(0)` which will remove the top level (Sales). Setting `columns.name` to `None` will remove the `Products`. So, after `df2` is created, add these lines...

```
>> df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
>> df2.columns.name = None
>> df2 =df2.reset_index()
>> df2

    year    client  P1  P2
0   2020    C   25.0    NaN
1   2021    B   20.0    NaN
2   2021    C   NaN 22.0
3   2022    A   10.0    NaN
4   2022    B   NaN 20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df = (df2.droplevel(0, axis=1)
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
      .reset_index())
```

```
print(df)

   year client    P1    P2
0  2020      C  25.0   NaN
1  2021      B  20.0   NaN
2  2021      C   NaN  22.0
3  2022      A  10.0   NaN
4  2022      B   NaN  20.0
```